# Does iOS 7 still require the iTunesArtwork image without alpha, without rounded corners and without file extension?

Tags: iphone, ios

Prior iOS 7 we had to include an iTunesArtwork file without an alpha channel and no rounded corners. It had to be in a specific color space.

Now the new [iOS 7 human interface guidelinges](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1) don't talk about the rounded corners. I think since iOS 7 the way we name icons changed. We can use an "Asset Catalog" and name icons whatever we want. But I am still confused about the iTunesArtwork file.

Can I just use one with rounded corners and alpha now?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is still required.
You should provide `iTunesArtwork@2x` and `iTunesArtwork`.

Source [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1)

**Edit:**

The iTunesArtwork files should not make part of your app target if your are submitting to the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

No, you still shouldn't put alpha or rounded corners. That's still applied by the store and by iOS.

The rounded corners on iOS7 are a little bigger and they're tapered at the ends of the radius, so there's no easy way to duplicate them either.

So I think that the icon will look slightly different on the store in iOS 7 compared to how it will look on the store in iOS 6 and earlier, but you just include a single image with no alpha.

Answer (score 0):

From the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1):

> When iOS displays an app icon on the Home screen of a device, it
>   automatically applies a mask that rounds the corners. Make sure your
>   icon has 90° corners so it looks good after the mask is applied.

and

> Avoid transparency. An app icon should be opaque. If the icon’s
>   boundaries are smaller than the recommended sizes—or you use
>   transparency to create “see-through” areas—the resulting icon can
>   appear to float on a black background, which tends to look especially
>   unattractive on the beautiful wallpapers that users choose.

So I don't think cannot do that, however you're discouraged to do so.